# Assertion fails on object copied using Kotlin copy

Tags: kotlin, junit

This is a problem that has been really puzzling. For some reason, equals method fails here:

```
val newItem = testPlaylistItem.copy(id = returnedItem.id, index = 0, updatedAt = newPlaylistFromDb.updatedAt)
assertEquals(newPlaylistFromDb, newItem)
```

As you can see, I'm just overwriting some properties that I know that change and I can't control (`id` isn't known since it's generated by the persistence and `index` and `updatedAt` are internally generated). Basically what I'm doing is ignoring them for the test at hand. This test is successful locally all the time but randomly fails when run by the compilation inside a Docker container (in CI pipeline). As displayed in the error, it shows a small difference: `2022-06-20T15:50:45.187Z` vs `2022-06-20T15:50:45.186Z`.

What I've tried so far is decompiling the generated bytecode into Java and I can't see the reason why this could happen. Apparently the copy method would pass the instant parameter by reference to instantiate a new object.

The stack and versions I'm using are:

- Docker image: openjdk:11.0.3-jre-slim
- Gradle 6.9.2
- Kotlin 1.4.10

Comment: can you share how both `testPlaylistItem ` and `newPlaylistFromDb` are initialized? Does your class under test have additional Date fields?

Comment: I'm sorry but sharing `testPlaylistItem` would introduce some confusion. Let me just say that a `PlaylistItem` has a default value for `val updatedAt: Instant = Instant.now()` and the rest of the fields are not nullable. `newPlaylistFromDb` is extracted from the database through Spring Data method `findByIdOrNull`. There are no additional Date fields.

Comment: Can you override `equals()` to ignore `updatedAt`, since you can't ensure that's equal (e.g. if your test takes more than 1ms to run)?

Comment: It's a good suggestion to workaround the problem. However I'd like to know the actual reason. What I did to avoid it is to generate an instant and copy it both on `testPlaylistItem` and `newPlaylisFromDb`